# How to find matrix of orthogonal projection from gram-schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm having a little difficulty understanding Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. I have a problem to apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to the system of vectors $(1,1,1)^T, (1,2,1)^T$ then write the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto 2-dimensional subspace spanned by these vectors. After applying gram-schmidt I found $v_1 = (1,1,1)^T, v_2 = (-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})^T$. I'm not sure what to do next to find the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto 2-dimensional subspace spanned by these vectors. Also, what exactly does gram-schmidt orthogonalization find? I'm just a little confused.

Comment: To start off , you should normalize your new vectors

Comment: okay so v_1 = $1/\sqrt{3}(1,1,1)^T and v_2 = $1/\sqrt{2/3}(-1/3,2/3,1/3)^T$

Answer (score 2):

Hint; your final vectors are not correct. The point of GS it to get an orthogonal set of vectors. Are yours orthogonal? You are starting off with two non orthogonal vectors , that is

$v_1=( 1 , 1 , 1)$ and $v_2= ( 1 , 2 ,1)$

The GS algorithm proceeds as follows;

let $w_1=(1,1,1)$

then we define $$w_2= v_2- \frac{\langle v_1 , w_1 \rangle}{\langle w_1 , w_1 \rangle} w_1$$

$$w_2=(1,2,1)-(4/3,4/3,4/3)=(-1/3,2/3,-1/3)$$
and it can be shown now that the set
$$S=\{w_1,w_2\}$$ is orthogonal and also spans the same subspace as the original vectors v.

If we normalize S to say $$S_n=\{(1/3,1/3,1/3),(\frac{-1}{\sqrt6},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt6})\}$$

In general to find the projection matrix P, you first consider the matrix A with your vectors from $S_n$ as columns, that is $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & \frac{-1}{\sqrt6} \\ 1/3 & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \\ 1/3 & \frac{-1}{\sqrt6} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

that is, we will have the orthogonal projection matrix equal to,

$P=A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$

Comment: oops, I think I must have mistyped the second vector. And that makes more sense now the point of GS. how can you find the matrix for the projection though with these though?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark Great, and I will try to update it with more info soon

Comment: Yes, I want to write the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto 2-dimensional subspace spanned by these vectors

Comment: Where does that final equation come from?

Comment: I won't exactly post the derivation here, but you can find it on online. Anyways, it has to do with the orthogonal decomposition,

Comment: here is a good derivation of it,http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/OrthoProj.pdf

Comment: @Quality The multiplication by $(A^TA)^{-1}$ in your last step where you did $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is redundant since you already normalized A (with orthonormal cols). Hence $(A^TA)^{-1} = Id$. There are two cases where $(A^TA)^{-1}$ is relevant (i) when A has orthogonal cols only from G.S. algo, then $(A^TA)^{-1}$ gives you the factors $\frac{1}{||v_i||^2}$, and (ii) the 2nd case is when A just has cols which are regular basis vectors of your vector space, and $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ gives you the matrix of orthogonal projection as stated in [Orth](math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/OrthoProj.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Gram-Schmidt finds, given a basis of a subspace, an orthonormal basis of this subspace. Its main tool is the following formula, which defines the orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec v$ onto another vector $\vec u$:
$$p_{\vec u}(\vec v)=\frac{(\vec u,\vec v)}{(\vec u,\vec u)}\vec u.$$

*What you should do:*

Find an orthonormal basis of your subspace and complete it in an orthonormal basis of $\mathbf R^3$. In this orthonormal basis, the matrix of the orthogonal projection on the subspace (generated by the first two vectors) is simply:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now the matrix of the projection in the original basis is given by:
$$A=PBP^{-1}$$
where $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the original basis to the new one.

Comment: But I only have 2 vectors, so P won't be a square matrix?

Comment: You have to complete the orthogonal basis of the subspace into an orthogonal basis of $\mathbf R^3$ first. Thus you'll have a $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: So I have to first find a change of basis matrix for this and the standard basis of R3?

Comment: That's it, @StrangeQuark…

Comment: For some reason I'm blanking on how to do this. Why wouldn't that be a 2x3 matrix too, or it would have an all 0 column which makes it not invertable

Comment: A change of basis matrix must be a square matrix because all bases have the same number of elements.. Once you have an orthogonal basis $(\vec u,\vec v)$ of the subspace, you can complete it with the cross-product $\vec u\times\vec v$, for instance.